# Width in CSS set to 100% but it only take 80%

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create header inside the header it has two box 1, 2. Inside box 1 it has two other box A1, A2. Don't know why but I can not set the length container full length of screen even though I set the width for it is 100% it still take 85% screen.

[image]

```css
.Header-Fixed {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 998;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  outline-style: solid;
  padding: 4em;
  outline-color: #E5E0FF;
  outline-width: 0.5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-color: green;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div className='Header-Fixed'>
    <div className='container'>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Could you show me why this happens? I am beginner with Front End.

Comment: `.Header-Fixed` has padding, that's why the inner container is not 100%.

Comment: Your html + css doesn't seem to do anything. Please edit your code (now snippet) to represent your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting padding on the `.container` box instead of the `.Header-Fixed` box like this:

```css
.Header-Fixed{
    /* padding: 4em; /* remove this */
}
.container {
    padding: 5em; /* just use padding here */
}
```

Also, if there is padding on any other parent elements (like `<body>`, etc.), that could be preventing it from taking up 100% of the screen width.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.Header-Fixed {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 998;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  outline-style: solid;
  padding: 4em; /* Remove this */
  outline-color: #E5E0FF;
  outline-width: 0.5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em; /* Change this to "padding: 1em 0;" if you want to keep the vertical padding but make it take up 100% of the width" */
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-color: green;
  align-items: center;
}
html {
padding: 0; /*This will remove the weird spacing between the edges of your page and your content */
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class='Header-Fixed'>
    <div class='container'>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```